# How to deal with filename with space in the url (Firefox)

Tags: html, url, firefox, content-disposition

I have a link (url) to cloud front

http://example.com/11111111-bbbb-8888-aaaa-12345678900aa?response-content-disposition=attachment;filename*=UTF-8%27%27tsv%20test.txt&Expires=1513693756

when I use this link not in the firefox everything works fine and I can download a file with name **tsv test.txt** but when I try to use firefox browser it works in wrong way since downloaded file has name **tsv** What is wrong?

Comment: Why not simply upload your files without spaces?

Comment: space are not good practice in url use underscore would solve headaches

Comment: are you triggering this url from a href, http request, or something else? There are different treatments.

Comment: Please post the full HTTP response sent by the server.

Comment: @brian17han this is a redirect url which is located in the location header when server return status 302

Answer (score 0):

If you it's a full HTTP Response, you can try to wrap your file name with quotes. My following code is for Java.

```
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=\"" + yourfilename + "\"");
```

Comment: As far as I see your solution on the server side. It doesn't work in the url